# Delete last value from UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

How can I easily delete just the last number in a UILabel, which has about eleven numbers, on the tap of a button?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString * str = myLabel.text;
if ( [str length] > 0 )
    str = [str substringToIndex:[str length] - 1];
mylabel.text = str;
```

Comment: says "string" is an undeclared identifier :S

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Corrected ;)